# ajax form redirects to server page?

Tags: php, ajax, json, jquery, redirect

I got this ajax form that when submitted, should send the info to the server, the server, based on the info sent should decide a form to send back, and then the ajax function should load that form into the page, and the user should be none the wiser of the coolness in the background. The form submits, the php and stuff processes it fine, sends back this cool object, but then it seems to be stuck on the page on the server that was processing it, and then links to a page that just shows the returned info. Not cool. Here's the code:

```
     $(document).ready(function() { 

        $("#game").ajaxForm(function(json) {
            if(json.status == 'OK') {
                $("#game").html(json.form);
            }else {
                $(".error_msg").html(json.msg);
            };
        });

    });
```

What should happen, is that the function rewrites the json.form to the correct div tag, but instead it goes straight to a page that just outputs the json object itsself. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and if you guys need more info, just ask! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

JSON in itself will return as an object, you must decode / parse it for it to display properly.

Comment: Well, the JSON has a form element (hence JSON.form) and the form is just some html starting with <form ........blah blah blah>

Comment: So you problem is that the instead of the form being written, the JSON Object is just displayed on a blank page?

Comment: Yes! That's the exact problem!